# Transition CSS3 doesn't works on safari and chrome, but works fine on firefox

Tags: css, safari, transition

I can not make the transition function on safari and chrome.

I have an animation on hover with keyframe (background-image move), and I apply an effect for the mouse out with transition, works perfectly on firefox, but on safari and chrome that doesn't works and use -webkit- doesn't change anything.

but the transition dont works on safari and chrome.

for the mouse over i have written this :

```
.fabanim_to_right_from_left_new_object_appears_1 .object-moved {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.fabanim_to_right_from_left_new_object_appears_1:hover .object-moved {
    -webkit-animation: toRightFromLeftNewObjectAppears 0.3s forwards;
    -moz-animation: toRightFromLeftNewObjectAppears 0.3s forwards;
    animation: toRightFromLeftNewObjectAppears 0.3s forwards;
}
```

and that is my keyframe :

```
@-webkit-keyframes toRightFromLeftNewObjectAppears {
 49% {
 -webkit-transform: translate(100%);
 background-position:right;
}
 50% {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-100%);
 background-position:left;
}
 100% {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0);
 background-position:left;
}
}
```

i have test millisecond too, but that doesn't works for me :(

What I did not do well?

You can see an exemple here : [test transition](http://fabricenatario.fr/cv/test.html)

Please help.

Thank you.